# Why is result of DrawLine invisible on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

Have a FM HD form.
on the form: button and image (TImage).

```
procedure TfrmImageEditor.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image.Canvas.Stroke.Color := $ffff0000 ;  // Red
  Image.Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.bkSolid;
  Image.Canvas.StrokeThickness:= 10;
  Image.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Image.Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0, 0), PointF(100, 100),1);
  Image.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

After I click the button I see a line, excellent red line... but only in Win32.
When I run the app in iOS simulator or real android I see nothing after clicking the button.

What should I do to see a line on the Image?

UPDATE: Delphi XE5, Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Your beginscene should be the first statement.